# Jquery find data attribute without class

Tags: jquery

I've read many posts on how to find an element containing a particular data attribute with a particular class but I need to find an element containing a particular data attribute that does NOT have a particular class.

Im trying to look for the div containing class **slide** but NOT class **bx-clone** that has **data-bkey** = 3 and add a class **selected**.

Heres my code I tried **NOW WORKS**

```
var selected = $('.default-slider').find('.slide[data-bkey=3]').not(".bx-clone").addClass('selected');
```

But as you can see it still adds class **selected** to the **bx-clone**.

Here is the group of divs in my code

```
<div class="default-slider">
<div class="slide selected bx-clone" data-bkey="3" style="float: none; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 238px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <img src="/images/buttons/c2a-button3.png" height="50px">
</div>
<div class="slide" data-bkey="1" style="float: none; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 238px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <img src="/images/buttons/c2a-button1.jpg" height="50px">
</div>
<div class="slide" data-bkey="2" style="float: none; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 238px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <img src="/images/buttons/c2a-button2.png" height="50px">
</div>
<div class="slide selected" data-bkey="3" style="float: none; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 238px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <img src="/images/buttons/c2a-button3.png" height="50px">
</div>                                              
<div class="slide bx-clone" data-bkey="1" style="float: none; list-style: none; position: relative; width: 238px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <img src="/images/buttons/c2a-button1.jpg" height="50px">
</div>
</div>
```

I have also tried the :not function as well and still get the same results.

```
var selected = $('.default-slider').find('.slide[data-bkey=3]:not(bx-clone)').addClass('selected');

var selected = $('.default-slider').find('.slide:not(.bx-clone)[data-bkey=3]').addClass('selected');
```

Heres a JSbin to see in action:
http://jsbin.com/xiyayu/1/edit?js,output

Comment: `:not(.bx-clone)` - missing the `.` in the `:not` tries - altho your first attempt seems like it should work

Comment: Just tested it and your first example works..

Comment: @JonathanCrowe Look at my http://jsbin.com/xiyayu/1/ and you will see its still selecting the first one (has bx-clone)

Comment: I take that back. I found an error in that last JSbin. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a clearer answer for those looking, I found I have to find the elements with the attribute FIRST, then filter out from there.

```
$('.default-slider')
                    .find('.slide[data-bkey=3]')
                    .not('.bx-clone')
```